# Rerun a sql file with goto

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus, goto

I would like to rerun the sqlfile every second, so my idea was to connect to the db with the bat file.
SQLPLUS connect to Oracle, run the query, allows the connection to exist, run the query ...

But SQLPLUS connected to Oracle and dont execute the query its only open the file.

How can i fix it

file.bat

```
@echo off
cls
echo exit | sqlplus username/passwor@host
:start
@C:\X\sysdate.sql
timeout /T 1
goto start
```

file.sql

```
spool C:\X\test.txt append
set serveroutput on
declare
    dat ...;
begin
    select to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    into dat
    from dual;     
    dbms_output.put_line('Some german words like Bratwurst und Sauerkraut'||dat);
end;
/
spool off
```

Thanks

Comment: After the file opend, Oracle disconnectted

Comment: What is the output you receive.

Comment: Day, Month, Year and the time in 24h

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ from your password and change the hr password to not have any special characters

@ refers to the sql file in your sqlplus syntax, so that might be confusing matters...

Comment: sorry i had a mistake in my connection, 

sqlplus username/password@host this is right now

my password had no special characters

Comment: @sandman - the `@host`, or the `@pwd` in the original `hr/hr@pwd` version, is the connection string not the SQL file - you need a space before the `@` for it to denote a file to run.

Comment: yeah once the @ syntax error was cleared up by the OP, I was going to mention the exit at the end, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* thing SQL*Plus is seeing it the `exit` you're echoing and piping into it, so that's all it does - exit.

You need to call the file as part of the SQL*Plus command line:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
sqlplus username/passwor@host C:\X\sysdate.sql
timeout /T 1
goto start
```

But you also need to add an `exit` to your `sysdate.sql` file, or it will hang waiting for input at the `SQL>` prompt.

You might also want to add `set feedback off`; and you might want to add the `-s` and `-l` flags to the SQL*Plus call too, to suppress the banner from the terminal screen and to exit if it can't connect to the DB for some reason:

```
sqlplus -s -l username/passwor@host C:\X\sysdate.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, now i have a working "loop", but now it connected to the db, do the query, disconnected and repeat ist .
And it always takes 5 seconds to the next connected.
But i need only one connection to the db: connection, rerun the query until I exit it.

And when the db connection is lost, the bat.file must continue running.

Comment: If you want to continue if the connection is lost - presumably SQL\*Plus would have to exit then - you'd need the batch loop like this to restart it. But on top of that, you want to loop forever inside the SQL\*Plus session, repeating the same query every second?

Comment: I have a billing running overnight and this billing relates their data from a database. Sometimes, unfortunately, the billing breaks off over night. So I would like to check the DB connection, if this is available all night over without breaks.